# Removing JPanel from a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, fsm

I have a State Manager for a game that contains a stack of States. Now in one of my states ("Menu"), I have two JButtons in a JPanel (the JPanel is added to the main JPanel that displays everything). When I click the JButton "Play", I remove the Menu state from the stack. However, the JButtons stay on the screen (even though when i peek() I see that the Menu has been removed from the stack).

I don't want to remove the buttons from the State, because I want to be able to go back to Menu and see my buttons there again. How can I remove the buttons along with the state?

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html)?

> A CardLayout object is a layout manager for a container. It treats
>   each component in the container as a card. Only one card is visible at
>   a time, and the container acts as a stack of cards. The first
>   component added to a CardLayout object is the visible component when
>   the container is first displayed.

Comment: The format of my GUI isn't the problem, I just want to get rid of a part of it.

Comment: @user1264811: you are misunderstanding Amir's suggestion. He's talking exactly about swapping "views" in your GUI. Read the tutorial on CardLayout to see what this can help you accomplish. 1+ to Amir.

Comment: I see how this can be effective; however, I want to have more flexibility in my states. My Play state that will need to be visible under my HUD state.

Comment: I'm in a state of 'HUH?'.  Using a nested layout, a GUI can have parts that are visible all the time, while other parts can be swapped using a `CardLayout`.  If that does not answer your question, please rephrase the question and provide some sketches or ASCII art of the GUI in at least 2 states.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming each state corresponds to a single `JComponent`, you can use the `.setVisible(false);` method to hide the item when the state is removed.

In this case, when you initialize the main component, you'd want to make sure all components have been added - then when you add/remove states, you can just toggle the visibility.